# Does an existing action get routed to before a mapped route is attempted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

If an action exists on a controller, does asp.net-mvc route to that action before attempting to process any custom mapped routes?

**Example.**

Say I have the following controller

```
public class ShopController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Shop(Category category)
    {
        // returns some result
    }

    public ActionResult CartItemCount()
    {
        // returns some result
    }
}
```

And I have registered the following route in my route collection:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Shop",
        "Shop/{category}",
        new { controller = "Shop", action = "Shop", category = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

What would happen if I had the following URL?
http://www.example.com/Shop/CartItemCount

**Edit**

I confused myself by thinking that the name of the mapped route was related to how it was processed. That is not the case, when it comes to url matching the name of the route does not matter.

As it turns out I had another route defined just above the one I gave in the example. This route, though named differently, was getting matched. I didn't even think to check it because, as I said, I thought the name given to a route somehow impacted the matching.

Comment: It depends on what other routes you have registered. Routes are matched in registration order.

Comment: @nemesv This comment led me to actually look at my other routes and find the issue. I've edited the question to reflect my findings. Thanks! If you want to insert an answer for this I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

The routes decide which action to use. If there are no routes defined, you wont hit an action even if it exists. Install [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) and fire off your url. It will tell you ALL routes that it matches and which one it has actually used.

Comment: `{controller}/{action}/{id}` is defined by default if I understand correctly. So even if I have not defined any specific routes, I should still hit actions if they match the default route, correct?  According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#url_patterns

Comment: @jeremysawesome. That's correct. But if you define your route first, it will override the default one. Install Route Debugger and play with the ordering of the routes. Route Debugger will should you which routes are matched and which will be used. FYI - It sounds like I'm promoting that tool - I'm not affiliated in any way, it's just really good. Pulled me out of plenty of holes.

Comment: Great! I'll take a look at the RouteDebugger tool. Thanks for letting me know about it :)